# swift anonymous function recursion

Tags: swift

I'm trying to write a function literal in swift with a recursive body - in this case it's simply to add all the values in a list.  I'm getting an error that "Variable used within it's own initial value".  Any thoughts on what might be wrong here?   Also I'm aware that what I'm doing here is a simple reduce and that it's build into Array, I'm just using this as an illustrative example of what I'm seeing elsewhere.

```
let list: Slice = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

var closure = { (memo: Int, list: Slice<Int>) -> Int in
    if (list.count == 0) {
        return memo
    } else {
        return closure(memo + list[0], list[1..<list.count])
    }
}

let value = closure(0,list)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
let list: Slice = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

var closure:((Int, Slice<Int>) -> Int)!
closure = { (memo, list) in
    if (list.count == 0) {
        closure = nil // remove retain cycle
        return memo
    } else {
        return closure(memo + list[0], list[1..<list.count])
    }
}

let value = closure(0, list)
```

EDIT:

see this video: [Advanced Swift at WWDC14](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/404/). from around 41:00. it shows the down side of this method, and better workaround.

Comment: Thanks, it seems the trick is that the closure variable has to be declared first and then assigned.  Do you know if this is a bug or a feature?

Comment: I think it's a feature. the compilers only refuses "Variable used within it's own initial value", this is just how we can avoid it. Declaring a variable with `!` type will be initialized as `nil`, this is the "initial value". Then, as a normal closure behavior, modified `closure` value can be seen from inside of closure.

Comment: @BrandonRoth: Because closures capture outside local variables used inside the closure when the closure is created, and the closure is created by the `{ ... }` expression, before the assignment to the variable `closure`. So the closure must capture something, it must capture a variable that already exists, before the assignment.

Comment: There is no video in that link called "advanced swift".

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old, but I've found another alternative:

```
let list : ArraySlice<Int> = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

let closure = { (Void) -> ((Int, ArraySlice<Int>) -> Int) in
   func f(memo: Int, list: ArraySlice<Int>) -> Int {
      if (list.count == 0) {
        return memo
      } else {
        return f(memo + list[list.startIndex], list: list[(list.startIndex + 1)..<list.endIndex])
      }
   }
   return f
}()

let value = closure(0, list)
```